# How extend a drilled hole

Tags: body-work, frame

How do I extend/make a hole oval? It is in a rectangular beam (6 cm) and needs to be extended 5mm in one direction.

When mounting a tow bar, I discovered that some holes in the tow bar are not aligned with the pre-drilled holes in my cars frame. So, I need to extend the holes in the car frame (since those in the tow bar are threaded and cannot be altered).

So, should I use a file and some patience? Or will some smart trick save me some time?

Edit: I ended up filing for about an hour and that made the trick. I think that an experienced metalworker could do it in much less time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking you can do one of four things:

- Use a larger drill bit and make the hole bigger, though 5mm (half a centimeter) is a bit of a distance to do this.
- Use the right size of drill bit (same as threaded bolt width) somewhat like a mill and elongate it. To do this, you'd place the bit horizontal to the hole and work it up and down slowly while applying sideways pressure to eat the metal away. This would work much faster than a file would. You'd need to be careful not to apply too much pressure while doing this or your drill bit will snap. (NOTE: I'm suggesting the drill would be running during this procedure.)
- Use a rotary tool eat away the metal.
- Use a Sawzall to chew up the metal. **NOTE:** This would be a last choice option. A Sawzall can do *a lot of damage* in a short period of time.

Comment: What do you mean by "rotary tool"?

Comment: Such as a Dremel. There are also air powered ones (such as those used to do head porting on engines).

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestions, Paulster2. A file was my tool of choice and it worked out this time.

Comment: @ChristianMadsen ... that'll work. Glad you were able to get it done.